# How can I get specific errors when trying to login using feathers.js

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

Whenever I try to login with the correct user and correct password everything is fine, but whenever I try to login with a not existing user or a mistaken password I just get the same mistake which is:

```
{
  "name": "NotAuthenticated",
  "message": "Invalid login",
  "code": 401,
  "className": "not-authenticated",
  "errors": {}
}
```

The expected outcome is to show: user doesn't exist. Or for example: given user and password doesn't match

here is what I'm doing on my code

```
var username = "givenUsername"
var password = "givenPassword"

 client.authenticate({
  strategy: 'local',
  username, password
}).then((authResponse)=>{
  console.log(authRersponse)
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.error(err)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done by default because it would allow an attacker to guess which email addresses or user names are registered on your system. You can always [customize the local authentication strategy](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#customization) to throw the errors you would like, for example by overriding [findEntity](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#findentity-username-params) and [comparePassword](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#comparepassword-entity-password):

```
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { NotAuthenticated } = require('@feathersjs/errors');

class MyLocalStrategy extends LocalStrategy {
  async findEntity(username, params) {
    try {
      const entity = await super.findEntity(username, params);
      
      return entity;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Entity not found');
    }
  }

  async comparePassword(entity, password) {
    try {
      const result = await super.comparePassword(entity, password);
      
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Invalid password');
    }
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authService = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authService.register('local', new MyLocalStrategy());

  // ...
  app.use('/authentication', authService);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daff, even though I've read this on the docs, I feel very thankful because I didn't know if that was going to be solution to the problem that I was having, Thanks for being so responsive!